# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-pro-sidebar.js?v=913080ef' does not provide an export named 'ProSidebar'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `pro-side-bar` library in React but when I run the code that's what I get in the console using the dev tools:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
> '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-pro-sidebar.js?v=913080ef' does not
> provide an export named 'ProSidebar'

I don't know why.

This is part of the code with its imports

```
import { useState, ReactNode } from "react";
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined";
import PeopleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PeopleOutlined";
import ContactsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ContactsOutlined";
import ReceiptOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ReceiptOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarTodayOutlined";
import HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutlineOutlined";
import BarChartOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BarChartOutlined";
import PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PieChartOutlineOutlined";
import TimelineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TimelineOutlined";
import MenuOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuOutlined";
import MapOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MapOutlined";

type ItemProps = {
    title: string;
    to: string;
    icon: ReactNode;
    selected: string;
    setSelected: (title: string) => void;
};

const Item = ({ title, to, icon, selected, setSelected }: ItemProps) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    return (
      <MenuItem
        active={selected === title}
        style={{
          color: colors.grey[100],
        }}
        onClick={() => setSelected(title)}
        icon={icon}
      >
        <Typography>{title}</Typography>
        <Link to={to} />
      </MenuItem>
    );
  };
```

I tried to check for the documentation and some other people but I don't find anything wrong. I am expecting that this is a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what documentation you are looking at but from what I can see of the [API](https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar?tab=readme-ov-file#api) `react-pro-sidebar` mainly exports named `Sidebar`, `Menu`, `MenuItem`, and `SubMenu` components, and few context provider components and hooks.

I suspect you meant to import and use the Sidebar` component.

```
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from "react-pro-sidebar";
```

You can rename it to `ProSidebar` if you like so you only update the import statement.

```
import {
  Sidebar as ProSidebar,
  Menu,
  MenuItem
} from "react-pro-sidebar";
```